# React native color wheel not working if it is used multiple times

Tags: react-native

I was having **Invariant Violation** issue on regular installation, thus I imported the script as a component and used it like the following

```
import ColorWheel from '../../components/ColorWheel';

<View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{width:'50%', paddingHorizontal: 5}}>
        <Label style={{fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 'bold', paddingVertical: 5, textAlign: 'center'}}>COLOR (IF Any)</Label>
        <ColorWheel
            initialColor="#ffffff"
            onColorChange={color => this.onColorChange(color)}
            thumbStyle={{ height: 30, width: 30, borderRadius: 30}}
            style={{ height: 180, width: 180, elevation: 100000}}
        />
    </View>
</View>

<View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{width:'50%', paddingHorizontal: 5}}>
        <Label style={{fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 'bold', paddingVertical: 5, textAlign: 'center'}}>COLOR (IF Any)</Label>
        <ColorWheel
            initialColor="#ffffff"
            onColorChange={color => this.onColorChange1(color)}
            thumbStyle={{ height: 30, width: 30, borderRadius: 30}}
            style={{ height: 180, width: 180, elevation: 100000}}
        />
    </View>
</View>
```

It works fine if it is used single time, but I need to use it multiple time (5 times for 5 different colors). It stops working then, Nothing happens if the image is clicked or if the thumb is tried to drag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where's the code for the ColorWheel component?

Comment: it is the ColorWheel.js in the package naming react-native-color-wheel. I have imported the JS file as a component for avoiding the invariant violation as mentioned in the question

Comment: cool. About the invariant violation, here's some solutions about it: https://github.com/netbeast/react-native-color-wheel/issues/43

More specifically here: 
https://github.com/netbeast/react-native-color-wheel/pull/47

Hope it helps

Comment: The problem is not the invariant violation anymore, i have already fixed it by following the solution in your given link, my problem is when I try to use it multiple times, it does not work